# How to prevent nvidia kernel module from loading Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, kernel, 64-bit, nvidia-optimus

I have a Nvidia Optimus Laptop with Ubuntu 11.10 and previous i used to blacklist nouveau
(by "sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf" and adding "blacklist nouveau" then executing "sudo update-initramfs -u") so the built in Intel graphic was used, it work with Unity 3D.

Now i have installed Ubuntu 12.04 64bit tried to blacklist nouveau nvidia nvidiafb nv and updating ramfs but lsmod still showes that the nvidia module was loaded.

How do i prevent this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module name is "nvidia" (which shows up in `lsmod`), but the actual filename is `nvidia-current.ko`. Therefore you need to add to `blacklist nvidia-current` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf` (filename does not matter). After that, run `sudo update-initramfs -u`.

Do note that this change applies only on the next boot. To unload the module in the current session, run `sudo rmmod nvidia`.

By the way, when you install Bumblebee, it'll automatically blacklist nvidia and nouveau. See [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)